# Appropriate place to write onclick event in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing jquery onclick event out side the jquery onready function in. If I write onclick function in jquery onready function, in what way it differs the flow of execution?

Eg:

```
  1. jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  });
 jQuery("#elementid").click(function(){
  });

2.  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#elementid").click(function(){
  });

  });
```

In what way the execution flow  of 1 and 2 differs. Which one would be best way to use real time?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Once the DOM is ready, you can bind events.
It's easy to see in firebug or something similar when you open up the NET tab.

Answer (score 2):

Number two is better. Number one might not work sometimes, as you might be selecting an element that has not loaded yet. By enclosing in a document ready handler, you can be sure all page elements have loaded before you reference them.

More generally...

```
// code that does not interact with DOM can go here, and will be executed
// before the has DOM finished loading.
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // code that needs to access the page elements/DOM goes here, and will execute
  // after the DOM has finished loading
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define the handler *outside* the DOM-ready function, chances are that the `#elementid` selector may return an empty value - if you wait for the whole DOM to be loaded, you will be safe.

On the other hand, you can delegate the handler to the document:

```
$(document).on('click', '#elementid', function(event){ ... });
```

This way the event will be listened by the whole `document`, just when a `#elementid` element is clicked - but that would be more expensive of course.

Comment: This is more like it ... This will work even if the DOM didn't load yet and will work on dynamically created elements. +1 for using `on` and deprecating `live`

Comment: Can you elaborate more about being more expensive? I don't get the point.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy the narrowest the scope of the delegate element [`document` in this case], the smallest number of elements you have to check: it's better to delegate the parent of the element you want to listen events of, so you have to traverse a smaller portion of the DOM.

Comment: OK I think I understand now. So instead of `document` you can use any selector but you must make sure that it got loaded in the DOM first right? or It will work any way?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy yes you have to wait, as usual. But as advised in Billy Moon's answer, you should put all DOM related stuff inside the `$(function(){ ... })` handler.

Answer (score 0):

it is always safer to write the event handler in onready, because otherwise there could be chances that your script will get executed before the desired elements are added to the dom

Answer (score 0):

If you want an event to work on your page, you should call it inside the `$(document).ready()` function. This is to make sure that all of your elements are being added to the DOM and ready to used.

Also from this [**docs**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29):

> The $(document).ready() function has a ton of advantages over other
>   ways of getting events to work. First of all, you don't have to put
>   any "behavioral" markup in the HTML. You can separate all of your
>   JavaScript/jQuery into a separate file where it's easier to maintain
>   and where it can stay out of the way of the content
>
> With $(document).ready(), you can get your events to load or fire or
>   whatever you want them to do before the window loads. Everything that
>   you stick inside its brackets is ready to go at the earliest possible
>   moment — as soon as the DOM is registered by the browser, which allows
>   for some nice hiding and showing effects and other stuff immediately
>   when the user first sees the page elements

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the code isn't executed until the DOM is ready.

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

`The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.`

If you execute the second code in a `script` element located at the start of your HTML or in the header, the button elements wouldn't be found and no event handler would be bound. Using `.ready` fixes that.

Putting your scripts at the bottom of the page (adjacent to ) also solves this problem for the same reason - by the time the script is parsed, the HTML will be converted to the DOM and you can traverse it.